# pass parameter to angular component after ajax request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, restangular

I am dealing with angular 1 component, I made a datatable component which accepts a dataset as a parameter.

here is how I am using `datatable` component.

`index.html`

```
...
<datatable dataset="ViewModel.dataset"></datatable>
...
```

`index.controller.js`

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('DashboardApplication')
    .controller('PagesIndexController', PagesIndexController);

  function PagesIndexController() {

    var self = this;

    self.dataset = {};

    Restangular.one('someurl').get().then(function( pages ) {
      self.dataset = pages;
    });
  }
})();
```

`datatable.component.js`

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('DashboardApplication')
    .component('datatable', {
      bindings: {
        dataset: '<'
      },
      templateUrl: '/frontend/templates/dashboard/components/data-table.html',
      controller: 'DataTableController'
    });

})();
```

`datatable.controller.js`

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('DashboardApplication')
    .controller('DataTableController', DataTableController);

  function DataTableController() {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self.dataset); // which is undefined!
  }

})();
```

The problem is I'm getting `undefined` for `dataset` in `datatable.controller.js`. Is there any solution for this?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$onChanges` life-cycle hook to see the value when it becomes defined:

```
  angular
    .module('DashboardApplication')
    .controller('DataTableController', DataTableController);

  function DataTableController() {
    var self = this;
    //console.log(self.dataset); // which is undefined!
    this.$onChanges = function(changesObj) {
        if (changesObj.dataset) {
            console.log(changesObj.dataset.currentValue);
        };
    });
  }
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a

```
controllerAs: 'vm'
```

line from your component which will bind the model to "this" in the your controller instead of $scope (also means you can reach your viewmodel as "vm" inside your view, like:

```
ng-if="vm.dataset"
```

But I think it will still be undefined in that exact moment, you have several options here:

1. you can pass the promise to the component and write a then on it
2. you can place an ng-if="dataset && dataset.length" where you call the component in your outer html. This way the logic inside  your component will only trigger when there is actually data in the property.

   ```
   <datatable ng-if="ViewModel.dataset" dataset="ViewModel.dataset"></datatable>
   ```
3. you can also write something like this in your component:

   ```
   $scope.$watch('self.dataset', function () { 
      if (self.dataset) { 
         alert ('hi'); 
      } 
   });
   ```

Comment: I'm using `component` which it does not need `controllerAs`. It uses `$ctrl` as `controllerAs` by default.